# React Native Cutom TextInput onChangeText not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, textinput

I want to create and use a CustomTextInput in React Native. I have created it as shown in the code below, but the onChangeText prop inside the CustomTextInput is not working correctly.

Despite extensive research, I couldn't figure out the reason behind the issue. What could I be missing?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';


const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

const CustomTextInput = ({ value, onChangeText, placeholder, style }) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={value}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={style}
    />
  );
};


  const handleTextChange = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTextInput
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleTextChange}
        placeholder="Custom, not working..."
        style={styles.textInput}
      />

     <TextInput
      value={inputValue}
      onChangeText={handleTextChange}
      placeholder={"Working.."}
      style={styles.textInput}
    />

    </View>

    
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  textInput: {
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

also you can check in here
https://snack.expo.dev/@cemyeten/handling-text-input

Comment: Can you elaborate on this; `"the onChangeText prop inside the CustomTextInput is not working correctly."`?

Comment: Oh, and you should not define a component (CustomtextInput) within an component (App). It will recreate that component from scratch on every re-render. That is probably why it's not working as you expect. Move it outside the `App`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your component outside the `App` function or a better way is to create a separate file for it because if you put it inside when you write text useState hook re-renders the `App` function to reflect it on UI and it makes your component out of focus.

Fixed code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const CustomTextInput = ({ value, onChangeText, placeholder, style,...other }) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={value}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={style}
      {...other}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleTextChange = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTextInput
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleTextChange}
        placeholder="Custom, not working..."
        style={styles.textInput}
      />

     <TextInput
      value={inputValue}
      onChangeText={handleTextChange}
      placeholder={"Working.."}
      style={styles.textInput}
    />

    </View>

    
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  textInput: {
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see **you have created component inside the component** and using it.

But, **as you are creating a functional component inside the component it will re-created every time when any state update will occur**.

Better option is to **move the CustomTextInput outside** the screen or any component that has state.

Eg.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const CustomTextInput = ({ value, onChangeText, placeholder, style }) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      key='a'
      value={value}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={style}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleTextChange = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTextInput
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleTextChange}
        placeholder="Custom, not working..."
        style={styles.textInput}
      />
     <TextInput
      value={inputValue}
      onChangeText={handleTextChange}
      placeholder={"Working.."}
      style={styles.textInput}
    />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  textInput: {
    width: '80%',
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your snippet: indeed, typing in your `<CustomTextInput>` component unfocuses the input, which I think is what you refer to as *not working correctly*.

This is because when your callback function `handleTextChange()` is called, it changes the value of `inputValue`. This will trigger a new rendering of `<CustomTextInput>`, which will create a new `<TextInput>` object, therefore deleting the previous one and thus unfocusing your input.

Replacing

```js
<CustomTextInput
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleTextChange}
        placeholder="Custom, not working..."
        style={styles.textInput}
      />
```

with

```js
<TextInput
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={handleTextChange}
        placeholder="Custom, not working..."
        style={styles.textInput}
      />
```

should work.